# How to do Shard Aggregation on DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aggregate-functions, sharding

Referring to https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xV-As-sYKyg&index=23&t=2758s&list=PLq2BHGbGb1H9wf6XktfGJ8b3vFt-c4H7W I am sure many of you have seen this image. A technique to gain better write throughput by adding random number to the hash-key[image]

On the read side, we need to sum up the individual query results into a total bucket (or something). As per line number 2. Store (for Candidate A. Total: 2.5M)

How do we achieve that? How does DynamoDB aggregate the individual query results to sum them into one total bucket. Does anyone have any idea?

And will the Sort-Key still be available once all aggregated to further reduce it in a where clause?

Thanks